# Xubuntu 18.04.4 login loop

Tags: linux, ubuntu, xubuntu

My laptop was running fine until I tried to install flutter without using android studio.Eventually,flutter got installed.but got stuck with login loop on laptop restart

Removed X.authority file didn't give any positive result

So when I tried to login through shell, I got an error which states that

> The command could not be located because '/usr/bin:/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable
>
> Lesspipe: command not found
>   Command dircolors is available in '/usr/bin/dircolors'
>
> The command could not be located because '/usr/bin' is not included in the PATH environment variable
>   dircolors:command not found

Ps: when I did echo $PATH
i got  /usr/lib/flutter/bin

Comment: Show us the code where you modified your `PATH` variable. If you don't know where it was, try `/bin/grep 'flutter' ~/.* 2>/dev/null`

Comment: @K7AAY do you think that duplicated one has the answer of this question?!

Comment: This post duplicates https://askubuntu.com/questions/1225962/xubutnu-18-04-4-login-loop-issues so as per https://askubuntu.com/help/duplicates the duplicate was deleted.

Comment: @Freddy I've ran the command you've told me and I got /home/kinesthetic/.bash_history:export PATH=$PATH:`pwd`/development/flutter/bin  and home/kinesthetic/.bash_history:export PATH="/usr/lib/flutter/bin" and another one is  /home/kinesthetic/.bash_history:export PATH=/home/kinesthetic/development/flutter/bin:$PATH

Comment: @Freddy the last and second last error are in .bashrc rather than in bash_hisory

Answer (score 0):

Thank you to those who tried to help me, but ultimately, I'm able to figure it out on my own.The problem was with flutter. After I remove flutter folder,.the login loop ceased..
Cheerio..!